# Kendogrid get detail row of parent grid

Tags: kendo-grid

is there a way I could get detail row from a hierarchical grid?

This is how I setup detail grid:

```
function setChildGrid(e){

    var detailRow = e.detailRow;

    detailRow.find(".detail-grid").kendoGrid({
           // datasource and all needed setup is here...
   });

}
```

And in my parent grid:

```
$("#parent-grid").kendoGrid({
   // datasource and all needed setup is here...
   detailTemplate: "<div>my template here...</div>"
   detailInit: setChildGrid
});
```

What I want is to be able to get all values in detail grid when saving the parent grid.

Can I not do like this to get those row details?

```
var findChild = $("#parentGrid").find("childGrid"); //
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the details grid based on the row.

Kendo renders details grid as below:

there are two row type
1.  `.k-master-row` with guid (this is the row in parent table which has further child grid.
2. `.k-detail-row` which is hidden and shown only when master row is expanded. This contains the children element `<div class="k-grid k-widget" data-role="grid">` as the details grid.

so, to find the child grid for a row.

```
var detailsGridForRow = $(givenRow).siblings('.k-detail-row').find('.k-grid').data('kendoGrid');
```

Comment: It should be `.siblings('.k-detail-row')` (singular `"detail"` not `"details"`).